# what is better way of getting windows version in python?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, version, platform

I am going to write a program that performs Windows OS version check, since I can do it with sys.windowsversion()[0] or with platform module that returns string not int what would be better way to get windows release version ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by calling [`sys.getwindowsversion`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getwindowsversion). For example this output:

```
>>> sys.getwindowsversion()
sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1')
```

is for Windows 7.

Source: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-November/026227.html

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to do this in C is via _WIN32_WINNT macro, whose values are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#macros_for_conditional_declarations). [sys.getwindowsversion()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getwindowsversion) can indirectly be used to determine _WIN32_WINNT as it exposes all the necessary bits.

```
import sys

WIN_10 = (10, 0, 0)
WIN_8 = (6, 2, 0)
WIN_7 = (6, 1, 0)
WIN_SERVER_2008 = (6, 0, 1)
WIN_VISTA_SP1 = (6, 0, 1)
WIN_VISTA = (6, 0, 0)
WIN_SERVER_2003_SP2 = (5, 2, 2)
WIN_SERVER_2003_SP1 = (5, 2, 1)
WIN_SERVER_2003 = (5, 2, 0)
WIN_XP_SP3 = (5, 1, 3)
WIN_XP_SP2 = (5, 1, 2)
WIN_XP_SP1 = (5, 1, 1)
WIN_XP = (5, 1, 0)

def get_winver():
    wv = sys.getwindowsversion()
    if hasattr(wv, 'service_pack_major'):  # python >= 2.7
        sp = wv.service_pack_major or 0
    else:
        import re
        r = re.search("\s\d$", wv.service_pack)
        sp = int(r.group(0)) if r else 0
    return (wv.major, wv.minor, sp)
```

Usage:

```
if get_winver() >= WIN_XP_SP3:
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN:

```
import ctypes
   try: # >= win 8.1
       ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)
   except: # win 8.0 or less
       ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```