# Windows version detection in Python not working

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, sys

I'm building a component into a Python 2.7 script that determines what version of Windows the script is running on.  I found a good solution located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471772/what-is-better-way-of-getting-windows-version-in-python) from another Stack Overflow post which seemed pretty straightforward and fit my needs (Obviously, I used the second answer).  Unfortunately, it does not seem to be working.  I've tried this script on two systems (Win7 32-bit and Win7 64-bit) and it outputs my else statement every time.

Here's my output:

```
Loaded os_version_detection function!
Detecting family of Windows...
Detected OS: Unknown!
sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1')
```

Can someone point out what I'm missing.  It feels like the fix should be pretty simple (a missing character, missing statement, typo, etc.) but I just can't seem to put my finger on it.

Here's my code:

```
def os_version_detection(started_by_function):
    global os_version
    global os_arch

    # Determine what family of Windows is installed.
    print("Loaded os_version_detection function!")
    print("Detecting family of Windows...")
    sys_info_raw = sys.getwindowsversion()
    if 'major=6, minor=2' in sys_info_raw:
        os_version = "Win8"
        print("Detected OS: Windows 8/2012!")

    elif 'major=6, minor=1' in sys_info_raw:
        os_version = "Win7"
        print("Detected OS: Windows 7/2008!")

    elif 'major=6, minor=0' in sys_info_raw:
        os_version = "WinVista"
        print("Detected OS: Windows Vista!")

    elif 'major=5, minor=2' in sys_info_raw:
        os_version = "Win2003"
        print("Detected OS: Windows 2003!")

    elif 'major=5, minor=1' in sys_info_raw:
        os_version = "WinXP"
        print("Detected OS: Windows XP!")

    else:
        os_version = "Unknown"
        print("Detected OS: Unknown!")
        print sys_info_raw
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `sys_info_raw` looks like a string when you print it, its type is actually `<type 'sys.getwindowsversion'>`, which apparently does not treat the `in` operator the same way the str type does. Try explicitly converting to string before performing your checks.

```
print("Loaded os_version_detection function!")
print("Detecting family of Windows...")
sys_info_raw = str(sys.getwindowsversion())
```

Result (on my machine):

```
Loaded os_version_detection function!
Detecting family of Windows...
Detected OS: Windows 7/2008!
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Converting to string fixed it right up!  Thanks for the second pair of eyes!