# __main__.pyinstallerimporterror failed to load dynlib/dll "shcore"

Tags: python, winapi, pyinstaller, pywin32

I use pyinstaller to pack a exe file.

It can run normally in my computer(Win 10).

But in another person's computer(Win 7),it shows that

```
__main__.pyinstallerimporterror failed to load dynlib/dll "shcore".
```

About `shcore`,I use

```
import ctypes
PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE = 2
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE)
```

What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimum supported client for [`SetProcessDpiAwareness`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness#requirements) is Windows 8.1.

And according to the [`PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness):

> In previous versions of Windows, there was no setting for
>   `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE`. Apps were either DPI unaware or DPI
>   aware. Legacy applications that were classified as DPI aware before
>   Windows 8.1 are considered to have a `PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS` setting
>   of `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE` in current versions of Windows.

You can only use [`SetProcessDPIAware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiaware) to set **System DPI Aware**

Comment: thanks bro,So could I use ``try...except....`` to catch this exception in windows 7?

Comment: The usual way to do this in C is via `_WIN32_WINNT` macro to determine the version of OS. You may refer to this answer, from Giampaolo Rodolà: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20804735/10611792